# How many ideals does the ring $k[x]/(x^2)$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field. How can I determine the number of the ideals that the ring $k[x]/(x^2)$ have?

Comment: The factorisation theorem tells you that the ideals of $k[x]/(x^2)$ are in bijection with the ideals of $k[x]$ containing $(x^2)$, via the projection. Can you guess the end ?

Answer (score 3):

Ideals of $k[x]/(x^2)$ are in bijection with ideals of $k[x]$ containing $(x^2)$. An ideal of $k[x]$ contains $(x^2)$ iff it is generated by $p(x)$ such that $p(x)$ divides $x^2$. You should be able to go from here.

EDIT: looks like someone beat me to the answer in the comments. I'm not sure if I should delete this answer?

Comment: I think you might be able to come up with a different proof by using the equivalence between $k$-vector spaces and $k[x]$-modules, though I haven't worked this out.

Comment: Just to point out, $k[x]$-modules are actually $k$-spaces $V$ with an endomorphism $T$ of $V$.